# Can you put a white circled border around a icon in html5

Tags: html, icons

I'm been searching the web for a while looking for a way to put a icon in a white border circle with transparent background,

Anyone got some input this? it's doable?

think something like

```
     <Code for circle> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> </circle end>
```

Btw, it need to work in a mobile browser. thx for everyone's time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) and [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) CSS properties:

CSS:

```
.rounded-icon {
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="rounded-icon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> </div>
```

jsFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x80obagm/)

Comment: Sry for first do something today, but haven't been able to use a computer the last couple of days.

This is what i was looking for, thx a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your circle icon is in a div with class "icon". I would suggest using an extremely large border radius in CSS to emulate a circle, and simply add a white border, say 2px wide:

```
.icon {
    -moz-border-radius: 999px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 999px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 999px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    border: 2px solid #fff
}
```

If you also want this to work in IE8, you may also want to refer to using PIE, here: http://css3pie.com/